# Apply a function to pairs of columns in a loop

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration, correlation

My data look like this:

```
a1 <- runif(30, 1, 100)
b1 <- runif(30, 1, 100)
c1 <- runif(30, 1, 100)
a2 <- runif(30, 1, 100)
b2 <- runif(30, 1, 100)
c2 <- runif(30, 1, 100)
dframe <- data.frame(a1=a1, b1=b1, c1=c1, a2=a2, b2=b2, c2=c2)
```

I want to calculate the correlation between a1 and a2, b1 and b2, c1 and c2, but I'd like to do it in an efficient way, avoiding writing one line of code for each correlation. I tried to write a for loop but I did not succeed.

Comment: Please use `set.seed` when using such functions as `runif` to ensure reproducibility

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option

```
lapply(split.default(dframe, sub("\\d+$", "", names(dframe))), cor)
#$a
#          a1        a2
#a1 1.0000000 0.1132033
#a2 0.1132033 1.0000000

#$b
#           b1         b2
#b1 1.00000000 0.09113974
#b2 0.09113974 1.00000000

#$c
#           c1         c2
#c1  1.0000000 -0.2066311
#c2 -0.2066311  1.0000000
```

We split your data frame column-wise and then iterate over the resulting list with `lapply`.

Comment: This works. But what if the names do not match? For instance, what if I want the correlation between a1 and b2, and b1 and c2?

Answer (score 2):

A base R idea,

```
sapply(unique(gsub('\\d+', '', names(dframe))), function(i) 
                                                cor(dframe[grepl(i, names(dframe))]))
```

which gives,

> ```
>               a          b           c
> [1,] 1.00000000  1.0000000  1.00000000
> [2,] 0.01987806 -0.2247265 -0.08667891
> [3,] 0.01987806 -0.2247265 -0.08667891
> [4,] 1.00000000  1.0000000  1.00000000
> ```

Answer (score 1):

In a tidyverse style,

```r
set.seed(123)
# for a reproducible way, set seeds.
a1 <- runif(30, 1, 100)
b1 <- runif(30, 1, 100)
c1 <- runif(30, 1, 100)
a2 <- runif(30, 1, 100)
b2 <- runif(30, 1, 100)
c2 <- runif(30, 1, 100)
dframe <- data.frame(a1=a1, b1=b1, c1=c1, a2=a2, b2=b2, c2=c2)
library(psych)
library(tidyverse)
dframe %>% 
    corr.test(use = "pairwise.complete.obs") %>% 
    .$ci %>% 
    rownames_to_column('pairs') %>% 
    filter(pairs %in% c('a1-a2','b1-b2','c1-c2'))
#>   pairs      lower            r     upper         p
#> 1 a1-a2 -0.2365720  0.135222126 0.4724741 0.4761839
#> 2 b1-b2 -0.5137963 -0.188401038 0.1843832 0.3187486
#> 3 c1-c2 -0.3523592  0.009060141 0.3681278 0.9621014
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>